# How do I search Twitter for specific emoji (Twitter Premium API)?

Tags: api, twitter

I want to collect different tweets that have certain emoji in them, but my search didn't yield any results. I'm not sure if I have to use [unicode](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) for the specific emojis and if yes how to write the python code. I'm using the Pandas python library.

```
def load_tweets(credentials):
    # testing with a sandbox account
    rule = gen_rule_payload("(( blm) OR ( blm) OR ( blm)) lang:de has:geo place_country:at -is:retweet",  
                            from_date="2020-05-27", 
                            to_date="2020-06-27",
                            results_per_call=500)
    print("Rule used: ", rule)
```

The [Twitter Premium API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/premium-operators) states this in regards to using emoji for searching tweets:

> Matches an emoji within the body of a Tweet. Emojis are a tokenized match, meaning that your emoji will be matched against the tokenized text of the Tweet body – tokenization is based on punctuation, symbol/emoji, and separator Unicode basic plane characters. For example, a Tweet with the text “I like ” would be split into the following tokens: I, like, . These tokens would then be compared to the emoji used in your rule. Note that if an emoji has a variant, you must use “quotations” to add to a rule.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Tweepy? I do not know whether Tweepy has support for premium search (pretty sure if does not). Your code snippet looks more like it is using search-tweets-python from Twitter.

Comment: yes, you're right... it's pandas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in case anyone ever has a similar problem, the issue was a missing bracket pair.

`Blockquote rule = gen_rule_payload("((( blm) OR ( blm) OR ( blm)))`

Apparently, for you to be able to use emojis as operators, you need to put all the keyterms in one big chunk separating it from the rest of your filter options (here: lang:de, has:geo, date restriction or whatever else you may be using).